# In a linked mailbox scenario, is the master account allowed to have the corresponding email address as proxy address?

Tags: active-directory, exchange

I read the documentation on [how to create linked mailboxes from microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/recipients/linked-mailboxes?view=exchserver-2019), but this is something that isn't answered there or I just don't find it:

It's clear that the mailbox account has to be configured with the primary mail address of a user, since it's exactly the responsibility of that account. Hence it will be listed with type `SMTP` in the `proxyAddresses` attribute of the corresponding active directory object.
Now, will the master account have this email configured as `SMTP` in its `proxyAddresses` attribute as well? Is there any rule restricting this or is there any best practice in regard to this?

The problem we are facing in our application is, that we currently have a customer scenario, where both accounts, master and linked mailbox account, have the same primay proxy address configured and we have to do more checks than normally to find out which one's the mailbox account. If assigning the same primary mail address to the master account is an anti pattern, I could use this as an argument in discussions with the customer. If not, well, then we would have to add those checks.

Answer (score 0):

Try below command to find primary account for linked mailboxes.

```
Get-mailbox -resultsize unlimited | where {$_.recipienttypedetails -eq "linkedmailbox"} | select primar*, displayname |export-csv "C:\linked.csv"
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. However, we're developing a .net application and I know how I could find out, which account is the master and which is the mailbox account. My question was, whether it is common practice to have the primary mail address configured in both accounts or not. Just to understand, if this is a mistake on their side or a common practice.

Comment: How about your issue?

Comment: Nothing changed. Got no reply answering my question, so I still don't know whether that scenario is considered to be an error or may be okay.